# Kotlin annotation @Parcelize reliability

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I heard about `Kotlin` `@Parcelize` annotation long time ago, but it still was experimental and now it is not, IDE still complains about implementing `Parcel` members, but it seems to work.

Does anyone using it? is it safe? It seems to work, but is it ready for production?

```
@Parcelize
open class MenuCategory(
        var id: String? = "",
        var title: String? = ""
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: its same with Serialize  ?

Comment: No, it same as implementing Parcelable just code is auto generated

Comment: Yep, we are using it in production. It works great

Comment: where did you see it's not in experimental anymore ? really like it, want to use it out of experimental :D

Comment: Documentation does not say that it is experimental anymore.

Comment: Just Lint error does not look reliable, but it does work and compile

Comment: im legit asking where i can see that, need to show the rest of my team

Comment: @a_local_nobody Just read documentation on IDE, Ctrl+Q

Comment: oh sweet, thanks :D